# Efficient way to replace strings in one file with strings from another file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, awk

Searched for similar problems and could not find anything that suits my needs exactly:

I have a very large HTML file scraped from multiple websites and I would like to replace all

```
class="key->from 2nd file"
```

with

```
style="xxxx"
```

At the moment I use `sed` - it works well but only with small files

> *while read key; do  sed -i "s/class=\"$key\"/style=\"xxxx\"/g"
>   file_to_process; done < keys*

When I'm trying to process something larger it takes ages

Example:

```
keys - Count: 1233 lines
file_to_ process - Count: 1946 lines
```

It takes about 40 s to complete only 1/10 of processing I need

```
real    0m40.901s
user    0m8.181s
sys     0m15.253s
```

Comment: It would help to include sample data from keys in your message. Good luck.

Comment: '40 s to complete only 1/10'... So now that it's more than 400s later, your job is done, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested since you didn't provide any sample input and expected output:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { keys = keys sep $0; sep = "|"; next }
{ gsub("class=\"(" keys ")\"","style=\"xxxx\"") }
1' keys file_to_process > tmp$$ &&
mv tmp$$ file_to_process
```

Comment: wow thanks so much  this is super fast real    0m0.273s
user    0m0.264s
sys     0m0.008s

Answer (score 1):

I think it's time to Perl (untested):

```
my $keyfilename = 'somekeyfile'; // or pick up from script arguments
open KEYFILE, '<', $keyfilename or die("Could not open key file $keyfilename\n");
my %keys = map { $_ => 1 } <KEYFILE>; // construct a map for lookup speed
close KEYFILE;

my $htmlfilename = 'somehtmlfile'; // or pick up from script arguments
open HTMLFILE, '<', $htmlfilename or die("Could not open html file $htmlfilename\n");
my $newchunk = qq/class="xxxx"/;
for  my $line (<$htmlfile>) {
    my $newline = $line;
    while($line =~ m/(class="([^"]+)")/) {
        if(defined($keys{$2}) {
            $newline =~ s/$1/$newchunk/g;
        }
    }
    print $newline;
}
```

This uses a hash for lookups of keys, which should be reasonably fast, and does this only on the key itself when the line contains a class statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate a very long sed script with all sub commands from the keys file, something like:

```
s/class=\"key1\"/style=\"xxxx\"/g; s/class=\"key2\"/style=\"xxxx\"/g ...
```

and use this file.
This way you will read the input file only once.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$0]++; next } { for (i in array) { a = "class=\"" i "\""; gsub(a, "style=\"xxxx\"") } }1' keys.txt file.txt
```

Note that the keys in `keys.txt` are taken as the whole line, including whitespace. If leading and lagging whitespace could be a problem, use `$1` instead of `$0`. Unfortunately I cannot test this properly without some sample data. HTH.

Comment: thanks steve that works like a charm but seems slower than my sed  real    1m19.551s
user    1m18.853s
sys     0m0.020s

Answer (score 0):

First convert your keys file into a sed or-pattern which looks like this: `key1|key2|key3|...`. This can be done using the `tr` command. Once you have this pattern, you can use it in a single sed command.

Try the following:

```
sed -i -r  "s/class=\"($(tr '\n' '|' < keys | sed 's/|$//'))\"/style=\"xxxx\"/g" file
```

Comment: The tr will append a | to the end of the text from keys so instead of "key1|key2" you'll end up with "key1|key2|". Not sure what sed will make of that but it's probably not what you want.

Comment: I just tested and sed will treat that as if the start of a line matches the set of keys so you'll end up with every line starting with style="xxxx".